# How do I know the number of keywords coming from a database?

Tags: oracle, jsp

select name from suggest where name like 'aero%' and rownum<=10;

I am getting only 8 keywords ( database has 8 keywords) but I want to count the number of keywords from database to my JSP program.

This gives 8 keywords:

```
 rs.getparameter("name");
```

But I want to count the keywords.  Can you give me any sample program?

thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 3):

Learn SQL :) There is a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..` which returns only one row containing the number of rows you would normally fetch (it is a bit more complicated, but this will do for now).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up information on JDBC, here are some good ones to get you started:

- http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/
- http://devdaily.com/java/edu/JDBC-SQLProcessor/Simple_JDBC_Example.shtml
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

To answer the question, I would either iterate on the ResultSets returned incrementing a counter, or just have query return count(name) and get that answer.